# xcode 8 created a second controller as a popup but just get black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I've tried using similar answers to my problem that i've encounter. I'm new to Xcode and I have one controller that contains a uiwebview that loads my website. i have coding to detect if a certain link is pressed. The issue i'm running into is when a certain link is pressed, I need my second controller to act as a pop up and display a different webpage. Everything works and that link is pressed my NSLog says that it in the second controller but the display is black. Here code that i have in the main view controller that loads my webpage:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.webViewer.delegate=self;
   NSString *fullURL = @"https://www.example.com?first_run=true";
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
   //NSLog(@"first page loaded=%@",url);
   NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
   [_webViewer loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
   self.webViewer.delegate=self;
   NSURL *strurl = request.URL;
   NSString *urlString = strurl.relativeString;
   NSLog(@"link clicked=%@",urlString);
   if(//not the right link do this){
   }
   else{//is the right link do this
      NSLog(@"found");
      self.popup = [[PopUpController alloc] init];
      [self.popup showInView:self.view animated:YES];
      return NO;
   }
}
@end
```

then for my second controller it's supposed to load a different webpage but just get a black screen:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   self.popupView.delegate=self;
   NSString *popupURL = @"https://www.example2.com";
   NSURL *url_popup = [NSURL URLWithString:popupURL];
   NSLog(@"popup page loaded=%@",url_popup);
   NSURLRequest *requestObj2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url_popup];
   [_popupView loadRequest:requestObj2];
}
- (void)showAnimate{
   self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
   self.view.alpha = 0;
   [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
      self.view.alpha = 1;
      self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
   }];

}
- (void)showInView:(UIView *)aView animated:(BOOL)animated{
   CGFloat x = self.view.center.x - (aView.frame.size.width);
   CGFloat y = self.view.center.y - (aView.frame.size.height);
   [aView setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,aView.bounds.size.width,aView.bounds.size.height)];
   [aView addSubview:self.view];
   if (animated) {
      [self showAnimate];
   }
}
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated. I've tried for 3 weeks searching and trying different solutions found on this forum but they all didn't work for mine. Not sure if I'm just not instantiating my controllers right or some piece of code that I'm missing. Thank you for your time in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
self.popup = [[PopUpController alloc] init];
```

simply creates an instance of `PopUpController` but doesn't load any of you UI elements with it.

Assuming you have designed `PopUpController` in storyboards, give it an Identifier such as "MyPopUp"

[image]

and then use:

```
// storyboard reference
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

// instantiate PopUpController from the storyboard
self.popup = (PopUpController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyPopUp"];

// show it
[self presentViewController:self.popup animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I get this error: WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x60800026b840>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'MyPopUp'. I named the storyboard identifier with the name MyPopUp but it still says it doesn't exist

Comment: *"doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'MyPopUp'"* ... you need to assign the identifier to the View Controller in your storyboard - **not** rename your storyboard. See the image in my edited answer...

Comment: Thank You soo much DonMag!!  That fixed it.